# Access to community pages from an iframe in an external website?

Tags: community

Is that possible to display community lightning pages from an iFrame in an external website ?

When I tried it, I obtained the following error :
Refused to display 'https://blablala.force.com/s/testcms' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Is that possible to modify the x-Frame-options value ?

Thank you

Regards

Julien

Answer (score 0):

It's a security measure from salesforce that would not allow you to iframe a salesforce Lightning page inside your website.

The right approach would be to use lightning out to take your components outside the platform and host it on to your site .